# Direction from gps coordinates

Tags: arduino, embedded, gps, sensors

I'm making a project which is based on traffic light management using embedded system. I'm using a Three way junction for this example. 1 gps coordinate will be fixed (i.e., of the traffic signal) and the other will be of the particular moving vehicle (lets say ambulance) coming from any direction. is there any way i can find out which direction it is approaching the traffic signal from the gps coordinates?

i considered using an RFID Tag at each junctions so that if an ambulance or any other emergency vehicle arrives, it can sense it and send the signal to the traffic light managing system

Comment: The last paragraph does not appear to be related to your question.  Do you have a question about that too?

Comment: This is a geodetic math question rather than a programming question,  The platform and the application domain are largely irrelevant.

Comment: _" is there any way i can find out which direction..."_ Yes, clearly, but surely your question should be about what that method is, not whether it exists?

Comment: GPS isn't suitable for safety-related purposes. Arduino isn't suitable for any purposes, least of all safety-related. Is this a serious project or just some artificial school assignment?

Comment: @Clifford Traffic light management is safety-critical so the platform is very much relevant. Designing a traffic light management system using Arduino is probably analogous to performing surgery on live patients using some "my little doctor" toy kit for kids and would probably yield about the same prison sentence...

Comment: @Lundin I kind of got the impression that this was a student "concept" project rather than a real application.  The question is about the maths of it, the application detail is entirely irrelevant other than an attempt to make it about code and so "on-topic".

Comment: @Clifford If so, the sooner someone talks some sense into them, the better :) Or they'll eventually pick Arduino for projects a professional setting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common methods; Haversine and Rhumb Line formulae.  Both are described at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.  For short distances it does not really make any difference which you use.

Both formulae yield distance and bearing. The Haversine formula for the bearing component for example:

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
```

where

`φ1`,`λ1` is the start point, `φ2`,`λ2` the end point (`Δλ` is the difference in longitude - `λ2 - λ1`).

So in code:

```cpp
#include <math.h>

double bearing_degrees( double lat1, double lon1, 
                        double lat2, double lon2 )
{
    double delta_lon = lon2 - lon1 ;
    double cos_lat2 = cos( lat2 ) ;

    double y = sin( delta_lon ) * cos_lat2 ;
    double x = cos( lat1 ) * sin( lat2 ) - 
               sin( lat1 ) * cos_lat2 * cos( delta_lon ) ;
    
    double bearing_rad = atan2( y, x ) ;

    // Degrees
    return fmod(bearing_rad * 180.0f / M_PI + 360.0f, 360.0f ) ;
}
```

The use of floating point math is computationally and code space heavy on an AVR based Arduino and even on an ARM based Due, with no FPU, floating-point math is generally best avoided, but in this case it is hard to avoid.  Moreover whilst using `float` would be both memory and computationally more efficient, with only six significant figures of precision, it will not be accurate enough for this application, where the distances are tiny fractions of an earth-circumference.  You need 5 *decimal places* of a degree to resolve to < 2 metres, which would require 8 significant figures.  `double` is good for 15 significant figures.

Comment: Notice that [avr-gcc implements `double`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Deviations_from_the_Standard) in a non-compliant way as 32-bit values, i.e. `double=float` except you use `-mdouble=64` which is only supported with avr-gcc v10+. Moreover, the [implementation is incomplete](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Shortcomings), in particular `atan2` is missing to date.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts. Good information.  It seems this platform might be ill advised for this task without a great deal of work.